# Connect/Push Outlook calendar to SharePoint (not vice versa)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, outlook, sync, synchronisation

I've received several requests from my user-base as to whether it was possible to publish an Outlook calendar to SharePoint, based on an existing Outlook calendar.

A team has a shared (not on SharePoint) calendar in Outlook, and they wish to retain the content of that calendar, and "push" it to SharePoint, so that others may sync with the calendar from SharePoint, and the team also has the calendar available on SharePoint.

We know that we can connect a calendar from SharePoint to Outlook. That is not what we need. **We need to other direction**!

I found the following URL http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/connect-outlook-shared-calendar-sharepoint-t3918771.html where a reply said that this was not possible. But the post is from 2009, so I am hoping that it is wrong/outdated.

Is this possible? If not, what are my options from there?

Comment: but what if its a shared calendar but sharepoint is trying to link to my personal calendar

Comment: this is SharePoint 2016 office 265 cloud

Comment: Quite late, but why not just share the Outlook calendar directly to other people within Outlook? Sending it to SharePoint just so that it can be re-downloaded to Outlook seems like introducing an unnecessary middle-man step.

Comment: @TylerH it might be, such as in the case I'm investigating, that the calendar content also needs to be public through the SharePoint site, for people with access to it but not to Outlook / Exchange.

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk Hmm, well you can share Outlook calendars externally of your organization/tenant. Even if that is disabled, it's probably better to _start_ with a SharePoint calendar and then sync that to Outlook rather than go Outlook -> SharePoint -> back to Outlook. The requested path here makes little sense in any case.

Comment: @TylerH I agree, better to start with the SP calendar and just edit that from Outlook, which is our preferred approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a calendar in SharePoint and apply an e-mail adress to the list of the calendar. You can send your meeting requests to the calendar list email adress (as attendee). For each meeting, an item is created, which is displayed on the calendar.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a little late. We ran into a similar scenario and needed to migrate multiple outlook calendars with hundreds of events to SharePoint. Our solution was:

- Create a SharePoint calendar
- Link that calendar to outlook
- Copy the old outlook calendar information to the newly connected
  SharePoint Calendar.

You can copy the old calendar information directly in outlook. Go to you calendar. Select the `View` tab and in the `Change View` dropdown select `List`. From there you can copy any/all the events and paste them directly into the new SharePoint calendar. These events should then should also show up in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/145337-importing-outlook-calendar-to-sharepoint-2010

You can export your outlook calendar to Excel, then import the Excel into a SharePoint list, or copy and paste into existing calendar columns via datasheet view.

I'm not sure how to handle recurrence though. Any ideas?

Also, I realize this doesn't answer your question due to lack of synchronization, but it might help someone who just needs to move an Outlook calendar to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Chris's suggestion, you could create the calendar in SharePoint and configure an email address to receive meeting requests. In your existing shared Outlook calendar, create a rule that automatically forwards meeting requests to the SharePoint email address.

Ref:

- [Enable and configure e-mail support for a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-HA010082307.aspx)

Comment: This should probably be a comment under Chris' answer, not an answer on its own, since it's really just commenting about an additional feature that Chris' solution would provide, rather than providing a novel answer to OP's question above.