# SP Calendar 2013 sync w/Outlook 2013 group calendar

Tags: 2013, calendar, outlook

I have 9 group calendars that I am trying to sync with SP2013. I am unable to get them to sync up with the Outlook calendars. When I try they just sync up with a new "Reports Calendar" on my Outlook  and create a new overlay in my Outlook vs. syncing up in SP.

We are running Outlook 2013 and SP 2013, about to upgrade to SP 2016. 
Currently the Outlook calendars are tracking outgoing deliverables and color coded with up to 8 colors per item/per day. We are creating one SP page to track this information for easy reference for management.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

> I have 9 group calendars that I am trying to sync with SP2013. I am unable to get them to sync up with the Outlook calendars. When I try they just sync up with a new "Reports Calendar" on my Outlook and create a new overlay in my Outlook vs. syncing up in SP

I think what you are saying is that;
You have 9 calendars created on Exchange (through Outlook), and you want them to automatically populate within SharePoint, or make the content visible on a SharePoint Page. Out of the box I don't think this is possible. You could export your calendar to excel and import as a list into SharePoint, but this would not make them stay in Sync.

Synchronization is designed to work the other way, you create the calendars on your SharePoint site, and then sync down to outlook, and Outlook will do its send/receive and maintain the data. (basically it's just connecting to the web services of SharePoint to read and write to the calendar, and not storing an Exchange copy of the data although it might be part of the local profile? )

At any rate, you need to create the calendars first on SharePoint (you can also choose to have one calendar, and then create 9 custom views to filter by each object you are tracking, and then sync each of those). Or you can just have the one calendar and sync everything in it.

It is possible to click on an item in your outlook calendar, press Cntrl+C to copy, and then click your newly sync'd sharepoint calendar and press cntrl+v. This is a manual solution, and will not keep the calendars in sync, its only meant to give you a means to migrate the data from the Exchange (Outlook) calendar to the new sharepoint calendars you are going to have to create.

I read there are 3rd party tools that will keep the two calendars in sync. Posted in this thread
[Connect/Push Outlook calendar to SharePoint (not vice versa)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38792/connect-push-outlook-calendar-to-sharepoint-not-vice-versa)

Comment: UGH, that isn't what I wanted to hear but I'm not surprised.  I kind of thought that might be the answer.  I know we have other calendars that populate in SP and sync back to Outlook but haven't heard of them going the other way.  There is so much detail in these that the copy/paste option is really not a good option at all.

Comment: Well, you can try the export import option. However, you would still need to build the Calendar View from the SharePoint List.

Comment: You could also publish to a web dav server (some server running IIS, with Web Dav enabled). Shown here, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2011/10/25/how-to-publish-a-calendar-from-outlook-to-iis-and-webdav/
If you have SharePoint onsite, then you already have an IIS web server, and probably running WebDAV :D
Then, use a Content Editor Web part, iFrame that displays the location of that published content. 
It would leave you with a web based calendar, not in SharePoint, but visible in SharePoint.

Comment: Yep, servers on site. I don't think they will accept no SP Calendars.  I need to decide if I want to force them to create these in SP and  just sync back to Outlook or tell the its not possible.